# Full text selection hotkey Ctrl+Shift Left/Right arrow does nothing

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I was just reading [lifehacker: How to Navigate Text Like a Keyboard Ninja](http://lifehacker.com/5321432/how-to-highlight-text-like-a-keyboard-ninja) and it states..

> **Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right arrow: Select text by whole words.** (Alt+Shift+Left/Right arrow on Mac)

And I just noticed today on my windows 7 PC, that this particular combination of inputs isn't working although the keys do work individually.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> *cursor moves across text, by whole words.*
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> *single character selection*
3. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> *nothing*

Is there something I can change in the `regedit.exe`? in order to enable `(Ctrl+Shift) + Left|Right` for full text selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found the solution [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/ctrlshiftarrow-shortcut-doesnt-seem-to-work/8fb025fb-3c79-4ade-90d7-87e08fef5ff1), uninstalled fortePivot and now have access to the (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>) + <kbd>Left</kbd>|<kbd>Right</kbd> action.

Answer (score 1):

If you have clownfish for skype installed it gets disabled as well!

So uninstall it or check if clownfish has any options for it.